# Django & Google Auth - Error 400 (OAuth2 Error)!!1

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I implemented the following views from the `oauth2client` documentation in Django 11.1:

```
@oauth_required
def get_profile_required(request):
    resp, content = request.oauth.http.request(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me')
    return HttpResponse(content)


@oauth_enabled
def get_profile_optional(request):
    if request.oauth.has_credentials():
        # this could be passed into a view
        # request.oauth.http is also initialized
        return HttpResponse('User email: {}'.format(
            request.oauth.credentials.id_token['email']))
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            'Here is an OAuth Authorize link:<a href="{}">Authorize</a>'
            .format(request.oauth.get_authorize_redirect()))
```

And the pages appear to work properly, but when I attempt to go through the flow, I get the 400 error saying it's a `Error: redirect_uri_mismatch`. I attempted to add my domain to the credentials section for the key, but I can't locate it. Here's a screenshot of what I see:
[image: Oauth setup page]

Should I be looking elsewhere? Is this a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Apparently, I was selecting "Other" for `Application Type` on the Oauth ClientID creation page, rather than "Web Application". Doing that solved the issue.